# Прописная или строчная в названиях учебных дисциплин

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишутся названия учебных дисциплин. "В этом семестре вам будут преподавать следующие дисциплины: "П/правоведение", "Х/имия", "Р/русский язык". На грамоте написано, что "названия учебных и научных дисциплин, направлений, специальностей: направление «радиофизика», направление «промышленность», специальность «инновационный менеджмент" пишутся в кавычках и со строчной буквы. Это верно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: **В этом семестре вам будут преподавать следующие дисциплины: правоведение, химию, русский язык.

1) **Названия учебных дисциплин пишутся со строчной буквы и без кавычек**: это научные термины (а не имена собственные), при этом нет необходимости заключать их в кавычки.

**Из словаря**: ХИМИЯ, 1. Научная дисциплина (область естествознания), изучающая вещества, их состав, строение, свойства и взаимные превращения. Прикладная х. Неорганическая х. Органическая х. Теоретическая х. Аналитическая х. Коллоидная х. Математическая х. Физическая х. // Учебный предмет, излагающий основы этой дисциплины. **Курс химии** в средней школе. **Урок химии**. 2. Разг. **Учебник** по этому предмету. Полистать перед экзаменом химию.

2) **Названия учебных и научных дисциплин, направлений, специальностей заключаются в кавычки**, если перед названием стоит **приложение**, например: я обучаюсь по специальности "международные отношения". В этом случае кавычки определяют границу между приложением и названием.

Но: **Специальность: международные отношения** (нет кавычек, строчная буква).

Answer (score 1):

Одни Вопросы, Ваша формулировка вынуждает меня напомнить и уточнить.
Строчн**а**я буква - это "маленькая". А "большая" - прописная или заглавная. Если вы это понимаете, то извините за менторство.

На "Грамоту" ссылаться не стоит,  тем более без точной ссылки.
А вообще тут вопрос понимания. Если это учебные предметы, названия курсов, то да, в кавычках. В этих случаях и заглавная выглядит в чем-то оправданно. Но как **научная** дисциплина (а судя по всему именно так и понимается говорящим) - без кавычек и со строчной? тут иного не дано.

Что касается случая с родовым словом "специальность" (см. Sibylla), то тут эти названия идут именно как названия, а потому я не согласен даже со строчной, а кавычки, "разумеется" нужнв. Но отдельный разговор, у нас родовое слово другое - *"дисциплины"*, и оно идет перед перечислением. Тут "названия" даже не пахнет.